# Travis tests returning undefined

Tags: javascript, express, github, jasmine, travis-ci

I'm testing with jasmine and it's working fine locally. However Travis CI is returning undefined for all the API tests. Example

4) Server GET /api/v1/orders Status 200
  Message:
    Expected undefined to be 200.
  Stack:
    Error: Expected undefined to be 200.
        at

Snippet from the tests

```
  describe('GET /api/v1/orders', function () {
    var data = {};
    beforeAll(function (done) {
      Request.get('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/orders', function (error, response, body) {
        data.status = response.statusCode;
        data.body = JSON.parse(body);
        data.number = data.body.length;
        done();
      });
    });
    it('Status 200', function () {
      expect(data.status).toBe(200);
    });
    it('It should return three Items', function () {
      expect(data.number).toBe(3);
    });
  });
```

Could the problem be from the 'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/orders' URL?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be starting your server anywhere so `localhost:3001` isn't available.

A good solution would be to use something like [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest). It would allow you to do something like so:

### app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const routes = require('./api/routes/routes.js')(app);

// We listen only if the file was called directly
if (require.main === module) {
    const server = app.listen(3001, () => {
        console.log('Listening on port %s...', server.address().port);
    });
} else {
// If the file was required, we export our app
    module.exports = app;
}
```

### spec.routes.js

```
'use strict';

var request = require('supertest');

var app = require('../../app.js');

describe("Test the server", () => {
    // We manually listen here
    const server = app.listen();

    // When all tests are done, we close the server
    afterAll(() => {
        server.close();
    });

    it("should return orders properly", async () => {
        // If async/await isn't supported, use a callback
        await request(server)
            .get('/api/v1/orders')
            .expect(res => {
                expect(res.body.length).toBe(3);
                expect(res.status).toBe(200);
            });
    });
});
```

Supertest allows you to make requests without relying on a specific port/url/other.

Comment: I hosted the app on heroku and have updated the api endpoints. It works now thanks